# PHP Rest, .htaccess Routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, url-routing

I'm using the REST API from this repo:

https://github.com/marcj/php-rest-service/tree/master/RestService

I'm running the REST service from a subdirectory `/mydir`. However, anything other than `/` does not generate any output.

Works:

```
use RestService\Server;

Server::create('/')
    ->addGetRoute('(.*)', function(){
        return 'It Works!';
    })
->run();
```

Doesn't work:

```
use RestService\Server;

Server::create('/mydir')
    ->addGetRoute('(.*)', function(){
        return 'It Works!';
    })
->run();
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your PATH_INFO configured correctly?

Look at: https://github.com/marcj/php-rest-service/blob/master/RestService/Client.php#L56-L57

You should setup the .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteRule (.+) index.php/$1
```

If you don't have the ability to configure PATH_INFO, you can set the url on your own:

```
Server::create('/mydir')
    ->getClient()->setUrl($_GET['url'])->getController()
    ->addGetRoute();
```